# grunt htmlmin - cannot get it to minify htm, minifies CSS and JS perfectly

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

concat grabs all the htm pages and puts them into 1 which is /templates/min/production.htm

What I am trying to achieve is /templates/min/production.min.htm, I get no errors in terminal window.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {
            controlCss: {
                src: ['UI.controls/assets/css/*.css'],
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/css/min/production.css'
            },

            controlJs: {
                src: ['UI.controls/assets/js/*.js'],
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/js/min/production.js'
            },

            coreJs: {
                src: ['UI.core/assets/js/*.js'],
                dest: 'UI.core/assets/js/min/production.js'
            }

            ,
            controlHtml: {
                src: ['UI.controls/assets/templates/*.htm'],
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/templates/min/production.htm'
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
            controlCss: {
                src: 'UI.controls/assets/css/min/production.css',
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/css/min/production.min.css'
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            controlJs: {
                src: 'UI.controls/assets/js/min/production.js',
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/js/min/production.min.js'
            },

            coreJs: {
                src: 'UI.core/assets/js/min/production.js',
                dest: 'UI.core/assets/js/min/production.min.js'
            }
        },

       
        htmlmin: {
            controlHtml: {
                options: {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'expand',
                src: 'UI.controls/assets/templates/min/production.htm',
                dest: 'UI.controls/assets/templates/min/production.min.htm'
            }
        }
        


    });

    // 2. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'cssmin', 'uglify', 'htmlmin']);

};
```

[image: @mario your way]

@mario this is running the code your way, and it seems to not find the source file... but I think it's supposed to be destination: source... not source: destination.. I'm going to post the response I get when doing destination: source too

[image: @mario my way ie my code posted above]

This is the response I'm getting in my terminal window while running the code as I posted above.

[image: changing it to destination: source]

@mario it seems to be freezing on reading the `production.htm`.

[image: grunt version]

Is it anything to do with my grunt version? Must I have version 4.0? I have 4.5, should it still work? Also there are many other errors, any of them ring any bells into why my html is not minifying?

Comment: htmlmin section doesn't seem to be doing anything

Answer (score 0):

According to [htmlmin documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin), you have to write the task like this:

```
    htmlmin: {
        controlHtml: {
            options: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true
            },
            files: {
                 'UI.controls/assets/templates/min/production.htm': 'UI.controls/assets/templates/min/production.min.htm'
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: cheers for the reply... but have already given that a try and didn't work :( and did just try again, and still not minifying my html

Comment: What happen if you type _grunt htmlmin -v_ in your console?

Comment: and i think its files{ destination: source } not files{source: destination}

Comment: shall i try it with my original code or code recommended by you? and can you confirm whether its source: destination or destination source? as when i try destion: source it freezes on running htmlmin..

Comment: Both if you want please. My code is based in documentation, but yours maybe works too.